# Mermaid.js: process external.md file

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am using mermaid.js for some time however I always wanted to be able to render external `.md` files in my `.html` page. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: I think this will really depend on what markdown renderer you're using. Can you provide a little more information about your setup?

Comment: As i mentioned I am using mermaid.js library (https://knsv.github.io/mermaid/)

Comment: What I mean is, I don't think in its default state, mermaid will allow you to import an external file. If you are integrating it with a program or renderer that will allow that, it would be helpful to know more about the application.